# Blend file completely bricked, crashes when opening

Tags: blend-files

I have a file that is completely bricked. It crashes when I open it and when I try to append it into another file.

I have no back-ups and no autosave,it was last opened on Blender 3.0 and the debug log says "EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION".

Is there any way to recover the contents of the file? [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EVIpKn_MNiqdPvYABjtyGacrfKYC2-Z6/view) is the file if you want to take a look.

The Debug log is here for anyone who wants to take a look:

```
graph_id_tag_update: id=GRScene Collection flags=COPY_ON_WRITE source=USER_EDIT
graph_id_tag_update: id=SCScene flags=COPY_ON_WRITE source=USER_EDIT
graph_id_tag_update: id=GRCollection flags=COPY_ON_WRITE source=USER_EDIT
graph_id_tag_update: id=GROVERRIDE_RESYNC_LEFTOVERS flags=COPY_ON_WRITE source=USER_EDIT
graph_id_tag_update: id=GRScene Collection flags=TRANSFORM, GEOMETRY, COPY_ON_WRITE source=USER_EDIT
graph_id_tag_update: id=SCScene flags=TRANSFORM, GEOMETRY, COPY_ON_WRITE source=USER_EDIT
graph_id_tag_update: id=SCScene flags=TRANSFORM, GEOMETRY, COPY_ON_WRITE source=USER_EDIT
graph_id_tag_update: id=GRScene Collection flags=COPY_ON_WRITE source=USER_EDIT
graph_id_tag_update: id=SCScene flags=COPY_ON_WRITE source=USER_EDIT
graph_id_tag_update: id=GRCollection flags=COPY_ON_WRITE source=USER_EDIT
graph_id_tag_update: id=GROVERRIDE_RESYNC_LEFTOVERS flags=COPY_ON_WRITE source=USER_EDIT
DEG_relations_tag_update: Tagging relations for update.
graph_id_tag_update: id=GRScene Collection flags=COPY_ON_WRITE source=USER_EDIT
graph_id_tag_update: id=SCScene flags=COPY_ON_WRITE source=USER_EDIT
graph_id_tag_update: id=GRCollection flags=COPY_ON_WRITE source=USER_EDIT
graph_id_tag_update: id=GROVERRIDE_RESYNC_LEFTOVERS flags=COPY_ON_WRITE source=USER_EDIT
graph_id_tag_update: id=GRScene Collection flags=COPY_ON_WRITE source=USER_EDIT
graph_id_tag_update: id=SCScene flags=COPY_ON_WRITE source=USER_EDIT
graph_id_tag_update: id=GRCollection flags=COPY_ON_WRITE source=USER_EDIT
graph_id_tag_update: id=GROVERRIDE_RESYNC_LEFTOVERS flags=COPY_ON_WRITE source=USER_EDIT
DEG_relations_tag_update: Tagging relations for update.
ED_screen_refresh: set screen
time bl_operators 0.0130
time bl_ui 0.0530
time keyingsets_builtins 0.0010
time nodeitems_builtins 0.0050
bl_app_template_utils.reset('')
        addon_utils.enable io_anim_bvh
        addon_utils.enable io_curve_svg
        addon_utils.enable io_mesh_ply
        addon_utils.enable io_mesh_stl
        addon_utils.enable io_mesh_uv_layout
        addon_utils.enable io_scene_fbx
        addon_utils.enable io_scene_gltf2
        addon_utils.enable io_scene_obj
        addon_utils.enable io_scene_x3d
        addon_utils.enable cycles
        addon_utils.enable mesh_looptools
        addon_utils.enable curve_tools
        addon_utils.enable node_wrangler
        addon_utils.enable magic_uv
        addon_utils.enable add_curve_sapling
        addon_utils.enable add_curve_extra_objects
        addon_utils.enable add_mesh_extra_objects
        addon_utils.enable io_import_images_as_planes
        addon_utils.enable ant_landscape
mtree updater verbose is enabled
mtree Updater: Read in json settings from file
register_class(...):
Warning: 'mtree_settings_panel' does not contain '_PT_' with prefix and suffix
        addon_utils.enable modular_tree-blender_28
        addon_utils.enable greasepencil_tools
Registered Animation Nodes
        addon_utils.enable animation_nodes
        addon_utils.enable render_freestyle_svg
        addon_utils.enable add_mesh_geodesic_domes
        addon_utils.enable add_mesh_discombobulator
Python Script Load Time 0.8842
Warning, unregistered class: ViewLayerAOVPanel(Panel)
Warning, unregistered class: ViewLayerCryptomattePanel(Panel)
Warning, unregistered class: CyclesPresetPanel(Panel)
Warning, unregistered class: curvetoolsSelectedObjectHeader(Header)
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Removed 24 relations to no-op nodes
graph_id_tag_update: id=SCScene flags=TRANSFORM, GEOMETRY, COPY_ON_WRITE source=RELATIONS
graph_id_tag_update: id=OBCube flags=TRANSFORM, GEOMETRY, COPY_ON_WRITE source=RELATIONS
graph_id_tag_update: id=MECube flags=LEGACY_0 source=RELATIONS
graph_id_tag_update: id=MECube flags=COPY_ON_WRITE source=RELATIONS
graph_id_tag_update: id=MAMaterial flags=COPY_ON_WRITE source=RELATIONS
graph_id_tag_update: id=NTShader Nodetree flags=COPY_ON_WRITE source=RELATIONS
graph_id_tag_update: id=NTShader Nodetree flags=COPY_ON_WRITE source=RELATIONS
graph_id_tag_update: id=OBLight flags=TRANSFORM, GEOMETRY, COPY_ON_WRITE source=RELATIONS
graph_id_tag_update: id=LALight flags=COPY_ON_WRITE source=RELATIONS
graph_id_tag_update: id=OBCamera flags=TRANSFORM, GEOMETRY, COPY_ON_WRITE source=RELATIONS
graph_id_tag_update: id=CACamera flags=COPY_ON_WRITE source=RELATIONS
graph_id_tag_update: id=GRScene Collection flags=TRANSFORM, GEOMETRY, COPY_ON_WRITE source=RELATIONS
graph_id_tag_update: id=GRCollection flags=COPY_ON_WRITE source=RELATIONS
graph_id_tag_update: id=WOWorld flags=COPY_ON_WRITE source=RELATIONS
graph_id_tag_update: id=NTShader Nodetree flags=COPY_ON_WRITE source=RELATIONS
graph_id_tag_update: id=NTShader Nodetree flags=COPY_ON_WRITE source=RELATIONS
graph_id_tag_update: id=LSLineStyle flags=COPY_ON_WRITE source=RELATIONS
Depsgraph built in 0.005544 seconds.
graph_id_tag_update: id=SCScene flags=COPY_ON_WRITE source=VISIBILITY
graph_id_tag_update: id=OBCube flags=TRANSFORM, GEOMETRY, COPY_ON_WRITE source=VISIBILITY
graph_id_tag_update: id=MECube flags=LEGACY_0 source=VISIBILITY
graph_id_tag_update: id=MECube flags=COPY_ON_WRITE source=VISIBILITY
graph_id_tag_update: id=MAMaterial flags=COPY_ON_WRITE source=VISIBILITY
graph_id_tag_update: id=NTShader Nodetree flags=COPY_ON_WRITE source=VISIBILITY
graph_id_tag_update: id=NTShader Nodetree flags=COPY_ON_WRITE source=VISIBILITY
graph_id_tag_update: id=OBLight flags=TRANSFORM, GEOMETRY, COPY_ON_WRITE source=VISIBILITY
graph_id_tag_update: id=LALight flags=COPY_ON_WRITE source=VISIBILITY
graph_id_tag_update: id=OBCamera flags=TRANSFORM, GEOMETRY, COPY_ON_WRITE source=VISIBILITY
graph_id_tag_update: id=CACamera flags=COPY_ON_WRITE source=VISIBILITY
graph_id_tag_update: id=GRScene Collection flags=COPY_ON_WRITE source=VISIBILITY
graph_id_tag_update: id=GRCollection flags=COPY_ON_WRITE source=VISIBILITY
graph_id_tag_update: id=WOWorld flags=COPY_ON_WRITE source=VISIBILITY
graph_id_tag_update: id=NTShader Nodetree flags=COPY_ON_WRITE source=VISIBILITY
graph_id_tag_update: id=NTShader Nodetree flags=COPY_ON_WRITE source=VISIBILITY
graph_id_tag_update: id=LSLineStyle flags=COPY_ON_WRITE source=VISIBILITY
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Operation is entry point for update: GEOMETRY_EVAL_DONE()
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Operation is entry point for update: TRANSFORM_EVAL()
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Operation is entry point for update: COPY_ON_WRITE()
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Operation is entry point for update: COPY_ON_WRITE()
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Operation is entry point for update: SEQUENCES_EVAL()
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Operation is entry point for update: PARAMETERS_ENTRY()
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Operation is entry point for update: VIEW_LAYER_EVAL()
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Operation is entry point for update: TRANSFORM_LOCAL()
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Operation is entry point for update: COPY_ON_WRITE()
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Operation is entry point for update: COPY_ON_WRITE()
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Operation is entry point for update: COPY_ON_WRITE()
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Operation is entry point for update: TRANSFORM_FINAL()
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Operation is entry point for update: TRANSFORM_INIT()
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Operation is entry point for update: COPY_ON_WRITE()
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Operation is entry point for update: PARAMETERS_ENTRY()
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Operation is entry point for update: TRANSFORM_LOCAL()
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Operation is entry point for update: TRANSFORM_INIT()
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Operation is entry point for update: PARAMETERS_EVAL()
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Operation is entry point for update: COPY_ON_WRITE()
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Operation is entry point for update: GEOMETRY_SELECT_UPDATE()
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Operation is entry point for update: TRANSFORM_SIMULATION_INIT()
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Operation is entry point for update: SCENE_EVAL()
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Operation is entry point for update: COPY_ON_WRITE()
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Operation is entry point for update: OPERATION()
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Operation is entry point for update: TRANSFORM_FINAL()
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Operation is entry point for update: COPY_ON_WRITE()
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Operation is entry point for update: COPY_ON_WRITE()
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Operation is entry point for update: TRANSFORM_FINAL()
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Operation is entry point for update: TRANSFORM_INIT()
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Operation is entry point for update: COPY_ON_WRITE()
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Operation is entry point for update: COPY_ON_WRITE()
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Operation is entry point for update: GEOMETRY_EVAL_INIT()
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Operation is entry point for update: OPERATION()
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Operation is entry point for update: PARAMETERS_EXIT()
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Operation is entry point for update: TRANSFORM_EVAL()
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Operation is entry point for update: GEOMETRY_EVAL_DONE()
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Operation is entry point for update: COPY_ON_WRITE()
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Operation is entry point for update: TRANSFORM_LOCAL()
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Operation is entry point for update: TRANSFORM_SIMULATION_INIT()
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Operation is entry point for update: AUDIO_ENTRY()
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Operation is entry point for update: GEOMETRY_EVAL()
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Operation is entry point for update: GEOMETRY_EVAL()
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Operation is entry point for update: SOUND_EVAL()
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Operation is entry point for update: PARAMETERS_EXIT()
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Operation is entry point for update: TRANSFORM_EVAL()
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Operation is entry point for update: COPY_ON_WRITE()
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Operation is entry point for update: PARAMETERS_EVAL()
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Operation is entry point for update: AUDIO_VOLUME()
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Operation is entry point for update: TRANSFORM_SIMULATION_INIT()
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Accumulated recalc bits for SCScene: 8195
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Accumulated recalc bits for OBCube: 8323
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Accumulated recalc bits for MECube: 4286574467
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Accumulated recalc bits for MAMaterial: 8320
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Accumulated recalc bits for NTShader Nodetree: 8320
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Accumulated recalc bits for OBLight: 8195
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Accumulated recalc bits for LALight: 8320
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Accumulated recalc bits for OBCamera: 8195
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Accumulated recalc bits for CACamera: 8192
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Accumulated recalc bits for GRScene Collection: 8195
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Accumulated recalc bits for GRCollection: 8192
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Accumulated recalc bits for WOWorld: 8320
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Accumulated recalc bits for NTShader Nodetree: 8320
[SCScene :: View Layer]: Accumulated recalc bits for LSLineStyle: 8192
[SCScene :: View Layer]: deg_evaluate_copy_on_write on LSLineStyle (0000022881B5D5B8)
[SCScene :: View Layer]: deg_evaluate_copy_on_write on NTShader Nodetree (0000022881B5DAB8)
[SCScene :: View Layer]: deg_evaluate_copy_on_write on SCScene (00000228FF6B2078)
[SCScene :: View Layer]: deg_evaluate_copy_on_write on NTShader Nodetree (0000022881B5EC38)
[SCScene :: View Layer]: deg_evaluate_copy_on_write on MECube (0000022881B4CBB8)
[SCScene :: View Layer]: deg_evaluate_copy_on_write on WOWorld (0000022881B35038)
[SCScene :: View Layer]: deg_evaluate_copy_on_write on LALight (00000228FF14FC38)
[SCScene :: View Layer]: deg_evaluate_copy_on_write on MAMaterial (00000228FF148D78)
[SCScene :: View Layer]: deg_evaluate_copy_on_write on CACamera (0000022881B5E9B8)
[SCScene :: View Layer]: deg_evaluate_copy_on_write on OBCube (0000022881B80838)
[SCScene :: View Layer]: deg_evaluate_copy_on_write on GRScene Collection (0000022881B36E38)
[SCScene :: View Layer]: deg_evaluate_copy_on_write on GRCollection (0000022881B35F38)
[SCScene :: View Layer]: deg_evaluate_copy_on_write on OBLight (0000022881B80138)
[SCScene :: View Layer]: deg_evaluate_copy_on_write on OBCamera (0000022881B43938)
[SCScene :: View Layer]: layer_eval_view_layer on View Layer (0000022881B2F438)
[SCScene :: View Layer]: BKE_object_eval_local_transform on OBCube (0000022881B80838)
[SCScene :: View Layer]: BKE_object_data_select_update on MECube (0000022881B4CBB8)
[SCScene :: View Layer]: BKE_material_eval on MAMaterial (00000228FF148D78)
[SCScene :: View Layer]: BKE_light_eval on LALight (00000228FF14FC38)
[SCScene :: View Layer]: BKE_mesh_eval_geometry on MECube (0000022881B4CBB8)
[SCScene :: View Layer]: BKE_object_eval_local_transform on OBLight (0000022881B80138)
[SCScene :: View Layer]: BKE_object_eval_local_transform on OBCamera (0000022881B43938)
[SCScene :: View Layer]: BKE_world_eval on WOWorld (0000022881B35038)
[SCScene :: View Layer]: SEQ_eval_sequences on SCScene (00000228FF6B2078)
[SCScene :: View Layer]: BKE_object_eval_eval_base_flags on OBCamera (0000022881B43938)
[SCScene :: View Layer]: BKE_object_eval_eval_base_flags on OBLight (0000022881B80138)
[SCScene :: View Layer]: BKE_object_eval_eval_base_flags on OBCube (0000022881B80838)
[SCScene :: View Layer]: BKE_object_eval_transform_final on OBCube (0000022881B80838)
[SCScene :: View Layer]: BKE_object_eval_uber_data on OBCube (0000022881B80838)
[SCScene :: View Layer]: BKE_object_handle_data_update on OBCube (0000022881B80838)
[SCScene :: View Layer]: BKE_object_eval_transform_final on OBCamera (0000022881B43938)
[SCScene :: View Layer]: BKE_object_eval_transform_final on OBLight (0000022881B80138)
[SCScene :: View Layer]: BKE_object_select_update on OBCube (0000022881B80838)
[SCScene :: View Layer]: BKE_object_data_select_update on MECube (0000022882302B38)
Depsgraph updated in 0.012987 seconds.
Depsgraph evaluation FPS: -nan(ind)
loading preset: E:\Hard Disk\Blender3.0LTS\3.0\scripts\presets\keyconfig\Blender.py
FRS_set_context: context 0x00000228F2271EF8 scene 0x00000228F42DC0B8
Read blend: E:\Hard Disk\Blender3.0LTS\Berline.blend
Error   : EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
Address : 0x00007FF75E14AAA0
Module  : blender.exe
Thread  : 00001a70
```

Comment: Nope. That crashes for me too, either opening or trying to append. (Blender 3.0.1)

Comment: Do you know what could be done to recover data from it (meshes, uv maps...)?

Comment: Same here - Can't open it. Debug not very helpful (at least to me) either.

Comment: I included the debug log in your question to make it easier for people who know about these things to diagnose it- hope that's ok.

Comment: If you can't append from it into another file I doubt there's much hope I'm afraid. :^(

Comment: But isn't there a way to parse data from the raw file? I'm interested in the mesh data and uv maps